# express server on google cloud functions can not serve static file without trailing /

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, app.yaml

I hosted express server as google cloud function
when ever I hit following link it works perfectly

```
https://<cloud-function-link>/<project-id>/static/
```

but if I remove trailing slash / at the end `https://<cloud-function-link>/<project-id>/static` it redirects to `https://<cloud-function-link>/static` and give me 403 error

I want it to work with both trailing / and without it.

my app.yaml

```
runtime: nodejs12

handlers:
  - url: /static
    static_dir: public

  - url: /.*
    script: auto
```

my index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
require("dotenv/config");
//routes
const authRoute = require("./routes/auth.js");
const adminRoute = require("./routes/admin.js");
//middleweres
//converting body into json using body parser
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: true,
    credentials: true,
    exposedHeaders: ["auth-token"],
  })
);
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use("/static", express.static("public"));
app.use("/api/auth", authRoute);
app.use("/api/admin", adminRoute);

// starting express server
if (process.env.BUILD === "dev")
  app.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log("listning on port 5000");
  });

module.exports = {
  app,
}
```

;

Comment: Isn't it an app engine  not cloud function?

Comment: I deployed it in cloud function

Comment: So what is this `app.yaml` for?

Comment: If I do not put app.yaml then it gives me 404 
apparently cloud function can not identify static folder without app.yaml

Comment: I would like to replicate this, bu it seems to not working... how do you deploy this? what is entry point?